# jQuery showing last Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an output in my console like the one below however with my code that I have it is only showing the last Object "Three" why?

**Wanted Response:**

`One Two Three`

**Console:**

```
 Object {title: "One" }
 Object {title: "Two" }
 Object {title: "Three" }
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = "assets/js/data.json";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data, function(author, data){
            $('#title').html(data.title);

            console.log(data);

        });//Each Close
    });//JSON Close
});//Ready function closed
```

**Updated Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url     = "assets/js/data.json";
    var author  = "";
    var title   = "";
    var body    = "";


    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data, function(author, data){
            author += data.author;
            title  += data.title;
            body   += data.body;

            console.log(data);

        });//Each Close
    });//JSON Close

    $('#author').html(author);
    $('#title').html(title);
    $('#body').html(body);


});//Ready function closed

<div id="title"></div>
<div id="author"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle which shows your problem?

Comment: @Mritunjay Sure doing now

Comment: you are using `html()` which replaces the data.. try `append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "assets/js/data.json";
    var txt = "";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (author, data) {
            txt += data.title;
            $('#title').html(txt);
            console.log(data);
        }); //Each Close
    }); //JSON Close
}); //Ready function closed
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have used your example - see question I have updated it with code however the .html outside the loop is not displaying the html the console is fine

Comment: Thanks - I can get three titles and body but only one author :(

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` overwrite `$('#title')` everytime it runs.

you should join them in a buffer. concat the strings and send the concated string to `.html()` once for all

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are using  $('#title') is a id of an DOM  object.
It will always replaced each time you run the loop.
So the last of the loop will be displayed ie. "Three"

If you want to change that make use a class and add to the parent object each time.

Or append it

```
$('#title').html('');
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data, function(author, data){
        $('#title').html($('#title').html() + ' ' + data.title);

        console.log(data);

    });//Each Close
});
```